# Intellij GWT project does not create /WEB-INF/deploy directory

Tags: gwt, intellij-idea

By default gwt applications should have a directory in WEB-INF called deploy/yourmodulename which contains the .symbolmap files which are needed to de-obfuscate client side stack traces.

When I compile via Maven it automatically creates this directory. Unfortunetly this directory is never created when I run my project via Intellij.

I am not running a "GWT" Run/Debug configuration but rather a Jetty configuration that actually runs the GWT compiler with the settings set for your GWT facet and deploys the intellij "artifact".

Any idea why this directory is not present?

Answer (score 1):

Support for 'deploy' directory is added in [IDEA 12 EAP](http://eap.jetbrains.com/idea12) builds. Open the artifact editor, press '+' button on 'Output Layout' tab and select 'GWT Compiler Deploy Output' to add 'deploy' directory to the artifact.